# Strange behavior of find()

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
a = [1 2 2 1; 1 1 2 2]

%   1     2     2     1 
%   1     1     2     2
```

I want to find all 1's and put them to zero.

```
[~, a_i] = find(a == 1);
a(a_i) = 0

%   0     2     2     1 
%   0     0     2     2
```

Why is there still a 1 in the first row?

Comment: The question is interesting, and got a very good answer. But I suggest changing the title to something like _Strange behaviour of find()_. My first thought when I saw the current title (_find() does not work_) was "Of course it does"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that you are doing it, you are only getting *the column index* of the `1`'s since you are only using the second output of `find`.

```
[~, col] = find(a == 1)
%   1   1   2   4
```

When you use this as an index into `a` it's going to treat these as a linear index and change only the 1st, 2nd, and 4th values in `a` into `0`. Linear indexing is performed in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#Column-major_order) so this results in the output that you are seeing.

To do what you're trying to do, you need *both* outputs of `find` to get the row and column indexes and then use `sub2ind` to convert these to a linear index which you can then use to index into `a`.

```
[row, col] = find(a == 1);
a(sub2ind(size(a), row, col)) = 0;
```

It's a lot easier to use the single output version of `find` which simply returns the linear index directly and use that.

```
ind = find(a == 1);
a(ind) = 0;
```

Or better yet, just use logical indexing

```
a(a == 1) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand my error now ! :)